# Add member to guild using oauth2 and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, discord, discord.js

I want to add a member to a guild with Discord oAuth2 system but with the new Discord.JS update, it has changed... I searched but I didn't found anything...

My code was

```
await client.api.guilds(guildId).members(client.users.resolveId(interaction.member.id)).put({ data: { access_token: data.access_token, roles: (user?.[0]?.roles == "") ? [] : userRoles } })
.then(async () => {...
```

where guildId is a Guild.id, access_token is an access token generated with oauth2 (it worked with the old version) and user an object, parsed from my database.

I tried differently with Guild.addMember but it didn't work too (addMember is not a function)

Can someone help me?

EDIT: Just found an answer by myself... (see my answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I just fount while coding something else, to add someone to a guild, you can use the Guild.members.add function

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to achieve the same with API then here is axios sample:

```
const response = await axios.put(
            `${discordApiBaseUrl}/guilds/${serverId}/members/${userId}`,
            {
                'access_token': accessToken
            },
            {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bot ' + discordBotToken,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                }
            }
        );
```

Note access token should have `guilds.join` scope.